# large negative modulo giving wrong result

Tags: java

I have a piece of code that mods two long numbers. One of those longs is negative and the other is not. given a = -5865797 and b = 979667766 the answer should be 973801969. But it is resulting in -5865797, same as variable a. Not sure why this is happening.

```
long a = -5865797;
long b = 979667766;

result = a % b;
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have 3 and you want to divide it by 2. The integer division of 3 by 2 is 1. However you could not make a clean division, so there is a "leftover", also called the remainder of the division. The modulo operation returns you that remainder.

If you try now to divide 2 by 3, what you'll have is less then one element per part, that means that the integer division of 3 by 2 is 0 and the remainder is 2.

You can think of this as rule: Whenever you try to divide number "a" by a number "b" that is bigger than "a", the integer division will be "0" and the remainder will be "a". That means that if you do the modulo of "a" by "b" you will always get "a", which is what is happening in your case.

Regarding how different programming languages treat the signal for negative operands, check the page below

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#In_programming_languages

BTW, 973801969 is the result of a + b (-5865797 + 979667766).